# No image in UIImageView within custom cell

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, tableview

I am building a TableView with custom TableCell's. And to populate the cell's I am parsing some jSON. The issue is I can display text in two label's, but for some reason the image isn't showing up in the ImageView.

My TableCell.h class

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *storePhone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *storeAddress;
```

My TableViewController.m class

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.storeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.storePhone.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"phone"];
    cell.storeAddress.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"address"];

    UIImage *storeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"storeLogoURL"]];
    [cell.cellImage setImage:storeImage];

    return cell;
}
```

Also I am using the AFNetworking framework to parse the jSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the image to show by using the code below:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"storeLogoURL"]]];
[cell.cellImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imageData]];
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 5
I used Kingfisher. It is a powerful library for downloading and caching images from the web. You can download from github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher.
After you added to Swift Packages > Add Package Dependency

```swift
import Kingfisher

class ViewController: UIViewController {
     
    @IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let addURL1 = "https://it-guru.kz/img/one-service2.png"
        
        if let urlPhotos1 = URL(string: addURL1) {
            image1.kf.setImage(with: urlPhotos1, placeholder: UIImage(systemName: "folder"))
            
        }
}
```